# Error while using OUT parameter in custom workflow activity

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml, sharepoint-workflow

Update: 
How to create a out variable?Can anyone please help me find out what am I doing wrong in my code. I am getting the error...
**ErrorType 'System.Int32' for dependency property 'ListItem' does not match with value type 'System.String'.
Parameter name: value**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Serialization;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Workflow.Runtime;
using System.Workflow.Activities;
using System.Workflow.Activities.Rules;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace TestEmailDistributionActivity
{
    public partial class Activity1: SequenceActivity
    {
        EventLog _log = new EventLog("Email Distribution");
        SPList _list;
        SPFieldUserValueCollection objUserFieldValueCol;
        string semailsettingKeyword1;
        string semailsettingKeyword2;
        string sender;
        string semailsubject;
        string semailfrom;
        string toField;

        public Activity1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static DependencyProperty __ContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("__Context", typeof(WorkflowContext), typeof(Activity1));
        [DescriptionAttribute("__Context")]
        [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public WorkflowContext __Context
        {
            get
            {
                return ((WorkflowContext)(base.GetValue(Activity1.__ContextProperty)));
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.__ContextProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static DependencyProperty ListIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListId", typeof(string), typeof(Activity1));
        [DescriptionAttribute("ListId")]
        [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public string ListId 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return ((string)(base.GetValue(Activity1.ListIdProperty))); 
            } 
            set 
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.ListIdProperty, value); 
            } 
        }
        public static DependencyProperty ListItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListItem", typeof(int), typeof(Activity1));
        [DescriptionAttribute("ListItem")]
        [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public int ListItem 
        {
            get 
            {
                return ((int)(base.GetValue(Activity1.ListItemProperty))); 
            } 
            set 
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.ListItemProperty, value);
            } 
        }
        public static DependencyProperty RecipientsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Recipients", typeof(string), typeof(Activity1));
        [DescriptionAttribute("Recipients")]
        [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public string Recipients
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base.GetValue(Activity1.RecipientsProperty)));
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.ListItemProperty, value);
            }
        } 
        protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
        {

            _log.Source = "Share Point Workflows";  
           // _log.WriteEntry("Code entered into Excute Method");
            try        
            {                
                //Execute method as a elevated method  
                SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated elevatedExecuteMethod = new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(ExecuteMethod); 
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(elevatedExecuteMethod);
            }          
            catch (Exception ex)     
            {           
                _log.WriteEntry("Error" + ex.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);   
            } 
            return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;  
        }
        private void ExecuteMethod()
        {
           // _log.WriteEntry("Code entered into ExcuteMethod()");
            //retrieveing the Site object    
            SPSite _site = new SPSite(__Context.Site.ID); 
            //retrieveing the Web object             
            //SPWeb _web = (SPWeb)(__Context.Web);  
            SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb(__Context.Web.ID);
            //retrieveing the list object        
            _list = _web.Lists[new Guid(this.ListId)];  
            //retrieveing the list item object         
            SPListItem _listItem = _list.GetItemById(this.ListItem);
            try
            {
                using (SPSite mysite = new SPSite("http://dlglobaltest.dl.com/Admin/IT/Application%20Development%20Group/TestEmailDistribution"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb myweb = mysite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        _log.WriteEntry("message from activity");
                        semailsubject = _listItem["E-Mail Subject"].ToString();
                        semailfrom = _listItem["emalfrom"].ToString();
                        SPList settingsList = myweb.Lists["Settings"];
                        //SPListItem _settingslistItem = settingsList.GetItemById(this.ListItem);
                        //string sender = _settingslistItem["Sender"].ToString();
                        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
                        oQuery.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Sender' /><Value Type='Text'>NS@de.com</Value></Contains></Where>";
                        SPListItemCollection ColListItems = settingsList.GetItems(oQuery);
                        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in ColListItems)
                        {
                            semailsettingKeyword1 = oListItem["Keyword1"].ToString();
                            semailsettingKeyword2 = oListItem["Keyword2"].ToString();
                            sender = oListItem["Sender"].ToString();
                            //SPFieldUserValue objUserFieldValue = new SPFieldUserValue(myweb, oListItem["Recipients"].ToString());

                            if ((semailsubject.Contains(semailsettingKeyword1)) || (semailsubject.Contains(semailsettingKeyword2)))
                            {
                                objUserFieldValueCol = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(myweb, oListItem["Recipients"].ToString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < objUserFieldValueCol.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    toField = objUserFieldValueCol[i].User.Email;
                                    this.Recipients = toField.ToString();//**getting the error here.**

                                }
                                _log.WriteEntry(toField);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.WriteEntry("Error" + ex.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);   
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Actions file:**

```
<Action Name="get Recipients" 
            ClassName="TestEmailDistributionActivity.Activity1"
            Assembly="TestEmailDistributionActivity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ef7ee5e33fadc78e" 
            AppliesTo="all" Category="Custom">
        <RuleDesigner Sentence="get all column values from %1 and %3 from Settings list"> 
            <FieldBind Field="ListId,ListItem" Text="this list" Id="1" DesignerType="ChooseListItem" />
            <FieldBind Field="Recipients" Text="get Recipients" Id="1" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
        </RuleDesigner>   
        <Parameters> 
            <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext" Direction="In" /> 
            <Parameter Name="ListId" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" /> 
            <Parameter Name="ListItem" Type="System.Int32, mscorlib" Direction="In" /> 
            <Parameter Name="Recipients" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="Out" /> 
        </Parameters> 
    </Action>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
SPSite _site = new SPSite(__Context.Site.Url); 
SPWeb _web = (SPWeb)(__Context.Web);
```

When operating in an elevated context, you must re-create the site and web. You have re-created the site, but not the web. So the web is probably referencing a site in the wrong context.

I normally just do (make sure you Dispose the objects in a using)

```
SPSite _site = new SPSite(__Context.Site.Id); 
SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb(__Context.Web.Id);
```

Comment: I have modified the code as per your suggetion and right now I am trying to hard code the value. Everything is working fine now, but I do not know how to use the out parameter in code. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code from user346514 almost work, just pay attention to:

```
public string Recipients
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base.GetValue(Activity1.RecipientsProperty)));
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.ListItemProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Must be:

```
public string Recipients
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base.GetValue(Activity1.RecipientsProperty)));
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(Activity1.RecipientsProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Also, on the ACTIONS file:

```
<RuleDesigner Sentence="get all column values from %1 and %3 from Settings list"> 
            <FieldBind Field="ListId,ListItem" Text="this list" Id="1" DesignerType="ChooseListItem" />
            <FieldBind Field="Recipients" Text="get Recipients" Id="1" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
        </RuleDesigner>
```

Must be something like:

```
    <RuleDesigner Sentence="get all column values from %1 and %2 from Settings list. Store result on %3."> 
                <FieldBind Field="ListId,ListItem" Text="this list" Id="1" DesignerType="ChooseListItem" />
<FieldBind Field="ListId2,ListItem2" Text="this list" Id="2" DesignerType="ChooseListItem" />
 <FieldBind Field="Recipients" Text="get Recipients" Id="3" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
            </RuleDesigner>
```

The %1 , %2, %3 Should match and in the same order as .
These fields must be defined also on  but don't need the same order.

I know it's an old post, but just in case someone needs a example of  workflow activities with OUT parameters.